# Matching "y", "Yes", "YES" or "yes" case-insensitively in bash

Tags: bash

I have an if/then statement prompting for user input:

```
if [[ "$email_answer" = [Yy] ]]; then
```

How do I get that statement to accept the word "Yes", "YES" or "yes" in addition to "Y" or "y"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` for this:

```
case $email_answer in
  [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Is this POSIX compliant?

Comment: Yes, why not!!!